# RegisterHotKey from Windows Service application

Tags: service, delphi-xe

If I call `RegisterHotKey()` from the `ServiceStart` procedure it will fail with below error:

> ERROR_REQUIRES_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWSTATION

I couldn't find much information on this so I created a thread, made a window (`CreateWindow`) and called `RegisterHotKey()` from this context; However, it returns the same error, What is the Proper way to register a hotkey from a Service application?

Here is my code:

```
Function Makewnd(): integer;
Var
  Hwnd: THandle;
  uMsg: TMsg;
Begin
  Hwnd := CreateWindow('STATIC', 'DummyWindow', 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, HInstance, Nil);

  Writelog(pchar('CreateWindow HWND->'+inttohex(hwnd,8)));

  If (RegisterHotKey(Hwnd, 7000, MOD_CONTROL or MOD_ALT, VK_F12) = TRUE) Then
    writelog('hotkey set: MOD_CONTROL or MOD_ALT, VK_F12')
  Else begin
    Writelog(PWideChar('Error: '+inttostr(getlasterror())));
  End;

  while (GetMessage(uMsg, Hwnd, 0, 0) = TRUE) do
    case uMsg.message of
      WM_HOTKEY:
      Begin
        Writelog(PWideChar('Hotkey! ID-> ' + inttostr(uMsg.wParam)));
      End;

    end;
    Writelog('GetMessage=false');
    Result := 0;
End;

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  Service4.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TService4.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TService4.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  Writelog('ServiceExecuteing');
  while not Terminated do
  Begin
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(TRUE);
  End;
end;

procedure TService4.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
Var
  TID: DWORD;
  Handle: THandle;
begin
  writelog('ServiceStart');
  Handle := CreateThread(Nil, 0, @makewnd, Nil, 0, TID);
  //not using handle right now
end;
```

Comment: You can't, because services don't interact with the user desktop; there's no way for them to get keystrokes. The error value clearly says this, so I'm not sure what more you'd expect us to provide. `ERROR_REQUIRES_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWSTATION` seems very understandable to me.

Comment: To add to what Ken said, [Interactive Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502.aspx) were eliminated when [Session 0 Isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653293.aspx) was introduced in Vista. Prior to that, a service *could* interact with the user desktop (but only the desktop of the first user to login) if the `SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS` flag was specified in the call to `CreateService()`. That flag is no longer supported, and services can no longer interact with any user desktops.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know!

Comment: Can you write about the solution in the answer box provided and then tick the "accept". This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't

> To add to what Ken said, Interactive Services were eliminated when Session 0 Isolation was introduced in Vista. Prior to that, a service could interact with the user desktop (but only the desktop of the first user to login) if the SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS flag was specified in the call to CreateService(). That flag is no longer supported, and services can no longer interact with any user desktops. –  Remy Lebeau